# What constitutes a measurement?

Tags: measurements, interactions

In an intro quantum mechanics textbook theres some experimental/historical background, then the postulates are stated, then the rest of the text focuses mostly on the math. But there’s one issue I’ve never really seen discussed: exactly what a “measurement” is. I’ve seen the definition as “an interaction” but this isn’t very satisfactory.

For example, in the electron double slit experiment I’ve heard it explained as the electrons position is in superposition until it reaches the detector, which interacts with it and causes its wavefunction to collapse. But what about the air molecules the electron ran into? What about the photons that hit it? What about the electric forces arising from the particles making up the room/screen? Those are interactions, but the wave function doesn’t collapse, we still see an interference pattern.

I’m not sure the exact conditions the experiment was done under but there’s no way there was absolutely nothing the electron interacted with on the way to the detector. You might say “these interactions are so weak, it’s not surprising they don’t affect the particle”, then how strong does an interaction need to be to collapse the wavefunction? What effect do these negligible interactions have?

The mathematical framework doesn’t really address this question at all, it seems like the person performing the math has to decide when the interaction occurs then the eigenstate a of the measurements are considered. There’s no math I’ve seen which tells the person when the collapse occurs.

So is there an answer to this? Is there any attempt to answer this? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article on the [measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem) useful.

Comment: I disagree with your statement "there’s no way there was absolutely nothing the electron interacted with".  The electrons that reach the detector are the lucky few that don't interact with anything else first.  You could only carry out an electron double-slit experiment in a vacuum.

Comment: @Rich006 what about the electromagnetic interactions from the molecules composing the container? The very slight dipole moments should exert a force on the electron. Or gravity. Even without air present it still seems like the particle would be bombarded

Comment: @Ghoster so if I’m not mistaken the measurement problem is related to my observation that we need to decide when a measurement happens, it’s not really described by or predicted by the math. My question is similar, but apart from the math, when do we even expect the wavefunction to change?

Comment: Yes, what you are asking is the essence of “the measurement problem”, which has bedeviled QM since its inception. I know QM but am not an expert on [quantum foundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_foundations); I’m more in the “shut up and calculate” camp. As far as I know, physicists do not yet agree on the proper resolution of the measurement problem.

Comment: The way I (very vaguely) think about it is that “measurement” is the interaction of a quantum system with a system that can be treated as classical. One highly-developed approach is called [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence), but Wikipedia says that physicists don’t agree on whether it actually solves the measurement problem.

Comment: This is a deep area to which some people have devoted their careers, and I would love for physics to reach a definitive resolution, but until it does, I’ll just stick with “measurements are what we do with our laboratory instruments”, as unsatisfying as that operational definition may be.

Comment: @Ghoster "*The way I (very vaguely) think about it is that “measurement” is the interaction of a quantum system with a system that can be treated as classical.*" What is vague about it? Is there anything more concrete than a measurement with a "classical" laboratory instrument? I am not arguing, I am just asking.

Comment: @hyportnex OK, I guess it’s not that vague. But my impression is that decoherence theory is a sophisticated way of calculating what happens in the intermediate realm of interaction with not-quite-classical systems, and thus a more complete explanation. Do you know if that’s correct?

Comment: @Ghoster I have no idea. I really meant what I said and was not arguing, am just lurking to learn

Comment: [Other PSE questions about the measurement problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Measurement+problem) may be helpful. I haven’t read them all since there are so many.